Printing on different background colours by the result
The result of what I was expecting is not the desired one..
The output of the table, is messing up because of it.

so... the code is this one:
{% if (log.action) == "update"%}
    <td style="width: 150px; background-color: yellow;" >{{log.action}}
{% else %}
    {% if (log.action) == "insert"%}
        <td style="width: 150px; background-color: green;" >{{log.action}}
    {% endif %}
    <td style="width: 150px; background-color: red;" >{{log.action}}
{% endif %}

and what I need from it is just to print with background-color when the output string is equal to those 3 options (only those are the options).

The current structure leads to rendering multiple <td> tags for the same condition, causing the output to be messy. Instead of above code, use single <td> for all your conditions.
<td style="width: 150px; 
    {% if log.action == 'update' %} 
        background-color: yellow; 
    {% elseif log.action == 'insert' %} 
        background-color: green; 
    {% else %} 
        background-color: red; 
    {% endif %}">
    {{ log.action }}
</td>


Instead of nesting if's inside each other, consider an actual {% if %}...{% elseif %}..{% endif %}-structure
{% if (log.action) == "update"%}
    <td style="width: 150px; background-color: yellow;" >{{log.action}}</td>
{% elseif (log.action) == "insert"%}
    <td style="width: 150px; background-color: green;" >{{log.action}}</td>
{% else %}
    <td style="width: 150px; background-color: red;" >{{log.action}}</td>
{% endif %}

demo

A more clean solution would be to extend Twig and add a custom function/filter, e.g.
<?php
    $twig = new \Twig\Environment($loader);
    $function = new \Twig\TwigFunction('get_background_color', function ($action) {
        switch($action) {
            case 'update':
                return 'yellow';
            case 'insert':
                return 'green';
            case 'delete':
                return 'red';
            default:
                return '';
        }
    });
    $twig->addFunction($function);

<td style="width: 150px; background-color: {{ get_background_color(log.action) }};" >{{log.action}}</td>


You could also drop the inline CSS and use classes of course e.g.
<td class="{{ log.action }}" >{{log.action}}</td>

